# shooting a club: the complement of a stationary subset becomes non-stationary

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I do not understand the saying (in the Kanamori's handbook of set theory) that "this forcing produces ("shoots") a closed unbounded subset of $S$ in the generic extension, thus the **complement** of $S$ becomes **non-stationary**". Here, I do not understand 2 things: first is that "shoots" and "produces"
goes in the opposite ways in English (though I'm not a native English speaker) and the second is why **the complement** and not $S$ itself ?

[image]

Comment: "Shoot" as in biology, plants: upward growth, ascent. "After his 15th birthday, John really shot up, grew 2 feet in a year!"

Comment: The forcing builds a new club contained inside $S$. Since the new club is inside $S$, the complement of $S$ misses it completely.